# Wildcard RewriteRule for 301 redirects in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm working on setting up a 301 redirect in an `.htaccess` file and I can get it to *sorta* work, but I'm not sure why it's not picking up on anything after a specific URL in the rewrite rule.

I currently have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/old-path/page/(.*) /new-page/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works fine if I test it with `http://example.com/old-path/page` which redirects to `http://example.com/new-page`

But if I try this:
`http://example.com/old-path/page/test` it will 404 and not redirect to `http://example.com/new-page`

Overall, since I'm not 100% if there are any other pages from the old path that may be nested within the page I want to make sure that I'm catching any of them and just redirecting to the `new-path` outright.

So, I'm not sure if I'm setting this up incorrectly or if there is something that I'm missing?

Comment: .htaccess doesn't match leading `/` in pattern so it has to be: `RewriteRule ^old-path/page/ /new-page/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Ok, cool. I think that worked. Thanks!